# Maya python FBX export?

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, fbx, pymel

I am trying to convert an .obj file to fbx with maya's python interpreter in a docker image. I have tried the following 3 commands and none seem to work. In the docker image I mayapy is the python interpreter and I am running my command like:

```
mayapy maya_pipeline.py arg1
```

### COMMANDS and ERRORS

Mm.eval('FBXExportInAscii -v true')

```
Error: line 1: Cannot find procedure "FBXExportInAscii".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maya_pipeline.py", line 251, in <module>
    Mm.eval('FBXExportInAscii -v true')
 RuntimeError: Error occurred during execution of MEL script
```

pymel.core.other.FBXExport("/house")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maya_pipeline.py", line 251, in <module>
    pymel.core.other.FBXExport("/house")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
```

Mm.eval('FBXExport -f "/house"')

```
Error: line 1: Cannot find procedure "FBXExport".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maya_pipeline.py", line 249, in <module>
    Mm.eval('FBXExport -f "/house"')
RuntimeError: Error occurred during execution of MEL script
line 1: line 1: Cannot find procedure "FBXExport".
```

Imported libraries

```
import sys
import os
from maya import standalone, cmds
import maya.cmds
from collections import defaultdict
import maya.mel as Mm
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')
import pymel
```

Comment: Do you have fbx sdk installed? It is available on autodesk website. In sdk (python not others) are scripts you need.

Comment: maya has that built into it already

Comment: Make sure you have right sdk (there are many fbx versions/standards) Maya module seems to need something more, you haven't imported.

Comment: there are resources you may also need. fbx: http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff453265c9125faa23bbb5fe8.htm,topicNumber=d0e8312 and maya: http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_index_html

Comment: Can you verify that the FBX plugin is installed and loaded? Does it show up if you run `cmds.pluginInfo(q=True, ls=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work after reading this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python_inside_maya/cLkaSo361oE/LKs9hakE28kJ)